# If $f^p\in L^1([0,1])$ it's bounded a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

We know that being Lebesgue integrable does not imply boundedness of the function (e.g. $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$). However function in $L^p$ spaces are functions with some decay conditions.

Suppose we have a function $f$ such that for all $p\ge 1$, $f^p\in L^1([0,1])$, can we infer $f$ is bounded from above and below? if not can one bound it only from one direction?

Comment: I suppose your question is if $\cap_{1\le p<\infty} L^p([0,1])\subseteq L^{\infty}([0,1])$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams exactly.

Comment: You could look into the $BMO$ space (bounded mean oscillation). These functions are locally $L^p$ for each $0<p<\infty$ but need not to be locally bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't infer that.

Take $f(x) = \ln(x)$

$$\forall p \geq 1, \int_0^1 \ln(x)^p dx < \infty $$

edit : but if $\exists M, \forall p \geq 1, \|f\|_p < M$, then $f\in L^\infty$.

Indeed, suppose $M=1$, take $\epsilon >0$, and consider $\{f > 1+\epsilon\}$

You have $\mu ( \{f > 1+\epsilon\} ) (1+\epsilon)^p\leq 1$

But $\lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^p} = 0$, so $\mu ( \{f > 1+\epsilon\} )=0$ and $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Are there some restrictions which make the claim correct?

Comment: Very nice. Same logic says that it doesn't even work if you consider $0 < p$. Of course we don't want to go further than that since including $L^0$ would make this trivial. You might want to put absolute values though since $\log$ is negative in that region. Hah. I was just about to make a comment about uniform boundedness, but you got to it before I could.

Comment: @AlanWatts : see my edit, if your bound on the $\|.\|_p$ is uniform, you have the inclusion

Comment: This is a really great answer :)